# Header to define parameters for IOCTL?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to define an IOCTL function:

```
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

#define IOCTL_TEST_CODE CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0x1, METHOD_OUT_DIRECT, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)

....
METHOD_OUT_DIRECT was not declared in this scope.
FILE_ANY_ACCESS was not declared in this scope.
CTL_CODE was not declared in this scope.
FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN was not declared in this scope.
```

If I compile as is, it won't know what any of the parameters are so I `include <winioctl.h>` which gives me:

```
LARGE_INTEGER does not name a type.
DWORD does not name a type.
GUID does not name a type.
_ANONYMOUS_UNION does not name a type.
+ a lot more
```

Am I using the wrong header? I can't find any information on this

Comment: You also need to include windows.h

Comment: I did sorry, editted it. Still having the problem

Comment: It's part of the Device Driver Kit, now which part that's the question ... searching.

Comment: Strangely enough, it was working before I got a BSOD, guess I should've mentioned that

Comment: Found in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0\shared\devioctl.h` and also `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0\um\winioctl.h`  .  Adjust for your installed SDK kit (find-in-files is your friend).

Comment: Thank you, just found out #include ddk/ntddk.h works as well. Not sure why I didn't need it before